# Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled. Operation canceled

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, dotnet-httpclient, documentclient

I am trying to read data from a cosmos collection using `DocumentClient`, while trying to read, sometimes I am getting the following error.

**Code:**

```
var Client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(accountUri), accountKey);
var collectionLink = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(database, collection);
var query = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<T1>(collectionLink, feedOptions);
var queryable = query.AsDocumentQuery();
var list = new List<T>();
while (queryable.HasMoreResults){
    // note that ExecuteNextAsync can return many records in each call
    var response = await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
    list.AddRange(response);
}
return list.FirstOrDefault();
```

**Error:**

**Unable to read data from the transport connection: Operation canceled. Operation canceled**

I tried few threads related to this error but that doesn't help.

**Stack Trace:**

```
Exception: at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync(HttpConnection connection, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.HttpRequestMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.<>c__DisplayClass20_0.<<InvokeAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<<ExecuteAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- 
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ShouldRetryResult.ThrowIfDoneTrying(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteRetryAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, Func`3 callShouldRetry, Func`1 inBackoffAlternateCallbackMethod, TimeSpan minBackoffForInBackoffCallback, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BackoffRetryUtility`1.ExecuteAsync(Func`1 callbackMethod, IRetryPolicy retryPolicy, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Action`1 preRetryCallback) at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.InvokeAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, ResourceType resourceType, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.GatewayStoreModel.ProcessMessageAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.ExecuteQueryAsync(DocumentServiceRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

**Note: The collection might be frequently and parallely accessed.**

Please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please edit your question with some code ? Why don't you use the DocumentClient class in order to access to CosmosDb ?

Comment: @PMerlet, I have edited the post with code.

Comment: Where is `ToListAsync` coming from? Did you accidentally use the Entity Framework's `ToListAsync`?

Comment: @NickChapsas, I have updated the code

Comment: I can't see something wrong with your code other than the fact that you read the full request while only needing the first value. Can I ask, where does this code belong to? What class? A repository? If yes then what's the instantiation policy on it? It is once per usage, once per request? It is a singleton?

Comment: @NickChapsas, We used to instantiate once, in start up.


Additionally I have added the stack trace..

Comment: So wait, are you instantiating one DocumentClient per operation?

Comment: DocumentClient will be instantiated on the app start up (like singleton)